# How to create chained pipes to different observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, observable

I'm wondering how is it possible to call and process two different observables like this:

```
return this.restService.update('/events/' + data.ID, dbObj)
       .pipe(
        tap((response:any) => {
            console.error("1")
            this.restService.get('/data/' + userID + '/' + eventID)
                .pipe(
                    tap(response => console.log(response))
                );
            console.error("2")
        }))
```

`this.restService` is just a wrapper for http and it works. What's happen is that `events` is called fine and returns a result. Then `console.log("1")`, also the request to `/data` is send but now `console.log("2")` appears.

What I'm missing is the output of the "inner" `console.log(response)`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us also the service, because im kind of sceptic that the second request '/data/...' should work.

Comment: The service is really simple and works for all other part of my app
`
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class RestService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 baseURL:string = 'http://wscm.localhost/rest';

 get(path: any): any {
        return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseURL + path);
 }
}`

Comment: My point is that with this structure without, subscribing to the inner `restService.get` it should not fire the second call to the server.

Comment: Tell me if the switchMap works for you

Comment: After the first tests it looks like that `switchMap` really can solve my problem. But it still needs some more tests.

Answer (score 2):

To get the response from the inner observable you might want to try the `switchMap` operator, so that the thing that you return is something like this

```js
return this.restService.update('/events/' + data.ID, dbObj)
       .pipe(
        switchMap((response:any) => {
            console.error("1")
            return this.restService.get('/data/' + userID + '/' + eventID)
                .pipe(
                    tap(response => console.log(response))
                );
            console.error("2")
        }))
```

This way after the first observable `this.restService.update(..)` returns value, it will trigger the `switchMap` operator, that will replace the stream of `this.restService.update` with new one that is the response of `this.restService.get(...)`

Comment: I afraid a replace will be a problem, because later I want to modify some data which come from `update` and write it to the second stream...

Comment: If i get you write you want to use the stream response in the second stream, you can use it by accessing the `response:any` in case that you want to have both response in the same time, at the end of the stream you can try `combineLatest` opeartor.

Answer (score -1):

The service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class RestService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    baseURL:string = 'http://wscm.localhost/rest';

    get(path: any): any {
        return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseURL + path);
    }

    post(path: any, data: any): any {
        return this.http.post<any[]>(this.baseURL + path, data);
    }

    update(path: any, data: any): any {
        return this.http.put<any[]>(this.baseURL + path, data);
    }

    delete(path: any): any {
        return this.http.delete<any[]>(this.baseURL + path);
    }
}
```